# "Show more comments" link breaks for unregistered users if a comment is posted after page load

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, unregistered-users

I didn't report this earlier as it is such a subtle bug and difficult to reproduce. I first noticed this many months ago, likely right after the comment update that split the "add comment / show all comments" button in two.

I often browse "hot network questions". I don't have an account on all SE sites. If I leave a tab open for a while and somebody adds a comment to an answer or the question, the "show more comments" link on that particular answer does not expand the comments (instead it acts sort of as a link to #top). A page reload fixes this however, and **this only occurs for unregistered users**.

I don't have any kind of visualization of this because I can't reproduce it on demand for obvious reasons. (This bug *always* reproduces when somebody adds a comment, but getting somebody to add a comment on demand is more challenging.)

This report is a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237244/add-a-comment-show-all-comments-breaks-after-someone-posts-a-new-comment-b). My attempt to clarify the title to better reflect the content was rejected (I understand why, as the question hard to comprehend with all the edits, and I refrained from changing the content too much), and I figured posting a new question is the best way to clarify the issue, and bring to attention the fact that this regression is bordering on annoying yet remains unfixed many months after introduction.

I use Opera, but it's likely not browser specific as others have reported the same issue on Firefox and Chrome in the other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that the code that updates the comment links when new comments arrive will, incorrectly, mark *both* the "add a comment" link and the "show *n* more comments" link as disabled for anon users.

Specifically, looking at [the code](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/full-anon.en.js), the bug appears to be within the `setCommentsMenu()` function, which is called from `StackExchange.comments.realtimeMessage()` to update the comment count whenever a notification about new comments arrives.  It's kind of hard to pinpoint *where* exactly the bug is in the function, since it seems to contain several parts that need fixing, but I can at least observe the following issues:

- When the comment count is updated live, the "add a comment" link will be shown even if the user is not allowed to comment.  This doesn't match the behavior of the server-side code, which will only show the "add a comment" link to anons if there is no "show *n* more comments" link.  (This is sort of tangential to this bug, but I thought I'd mention it.)
- If commenting is disabled (specifically, if the `addlink-disabled` data attribute is set for the post), the `setCommentsMenu()` function adds the `disabled-link` attribute to both the "add a comment" link and the "show *n* more comments" link.  In fact, it does it *twice*: first it disables *all* comment links with:

  ```js
  if (this.jtBody.data('addlink-disabled')) {
      this.jCommentsLink.find('a').addClass('disabled-link');
  }
  ```

  and then later it, redundantly, disables both links specifically with:

  ```js
  if (this.jtBody.data('addlink-disabled')) {
      addLink.addClass('disabled-link');
      showLink.addClass('disabled-link');
  }
  ```
- The `StackExchange.comments.realtimeMessage()` function contains the line:

  ```js
  commentLink.removeClass('disabled-link');
  ```

  which looks like an attempt to re-enable some link or links after they've been disabled by `setCommentsMenu()`.  However, as far as I can tell, this line actually does nothing useful, since the `commentLink` variable actually points to the `<div>` containing the links, rather than to the link(s) themselves.

A workaround for this bug is now included in the [Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) user script, as of v1.24.  What it does, in effect, is monkey-patch the `setCommentsMenu()` method to add the following code at the end:

```js
if ( commentsCount > 0 && this.jtBody.data('addlink-disabled') ) {
    this.jCommentsLink.find('.js-show-link').removeClass('disabled-link');
    this.jCommentsLink.find('.js-add-link, .js-link-separator').addClass('dno');
}
```

Removing the `disabled-link` class from the "show *n* more comments" link is enough to make it functional; the next line just hides the "add a comment" link next to it, to make the UI more consistent.

---

**Update:** It looks like this has been quietly fixed at some point.  Specifically, the first two snippets quoted above have been replaced with just:

```js
if (this.jtBody.data('addlink-disabled')) {
    addLink.addClass('disabled-link');
}
```